# A "simpler" description of the automorphism group of the lamplighter group

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, geometric-group-theory, automorphism-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

I've copied over this question from [what I asked on Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4735181), in the hope that some experts can point me to some relevant references.

The lamplighter group is defined by the following presentation:
$$
L_N=(\mathbb{Z} _N) \wr \mathbb{Z} \cong\left\langle t, a_n, n \in \mathbb{Z} \mid a_n^N, t a_n t^{-1}=a_{n+1}, n \in \mathbb{Z}, a_n a_m a_n^{-1} a_m^{-1}, m, n \in \mathbb{Z}\right\rangle .
$$

In this paper about [AUTOMORPHISMS OF HIGHER RANK LAMPLIGHTER GROUPS](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.2271), they computed the automorphism group of a large class of groups containing the Lamplighter group.

> Theorem 3.2. If $d \geq 2$, then
> $$
> \operatorname{Aut}\left(\Gamma_d(q)\right) \cong \operatorname{Der}\left(\mathbb{Z}^{d-1}, \mathcal{R}_d\left(\mathcal{L}_q\right)\right) \rtimes\left(U\left(\mathcal{R}_d\left(\mathbb{Z}_q\right)\right) \rtimes \mathcal{K}\right)
> $$
> where $\mathcal{K}=\left\{\beta \in \operatorname{Aut}\left(\mathbb{Z}^{d-1}\right) \mid K^\beta=K\right\}$.

(When $d=2$, we have the lamplighter groups)

I was wondering if there is a more straightforward description & computation specifically for the automorphism of the lamplighter groups.

Any reference for this would be really appreciated.

Comment: Here are jsut some thoughts. The lamplighter group has a unique maximal torsion subgroup $Q$ and thus $Q$ is characteristic. Any automorphism maps $t$ to an element of the form $q t^{\pm 1}$ with $q\in Q$; and any such choice can be extended by $id_Q$ to an automorphism of the lamplighter group. Thus the automorphisms fixing q are given by $P\rtimes C_2$, where the action is given by inverting group elements.

Comment: You can take a look at Proposition 4.8 in arxiv:2110.09822. (But the result was known before, see the references given there. This is just an elementary proof.)

Answer (score 10):

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}_N[X^{\pm 1}]$ be the [Laurent polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_polynomial) ring over $\mathbb{Z}_N = \mathbb{Z}/N \mathbb{Z}$ , let $U$ be the [unit group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_(ring_theory)) of $R$ and let $\theta$ be the ring automorphism of $R$ induced by the map $X \mapsto X^{-1}$. Set $C = \langle \theta \rangle \simeq \mathbb{Z}_2$. Note that $C$ identifies with a subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(U)$ via restriction to $U$.

For $x,y$ two elements of a group $G$, we set $x^y : = y^{-1} x y$.

> **Claim.** We have $\operatorname{Aut}(L_N) \simeq R \rtimes (U \rtimes C)$ where $U$ acts on the additive group of $R$ via multiplication, $C$ acts on $U$ via restriction of the previous action and the action of $C$ on the additive group of $R$ is specified by: $f^{\theta} = - \frac{\theta(f)}{X}$ for $f \in R$.

**Note 1.** We actually have an explicit [description of $U$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31007/what-are-the-units-in-the-ring-of-laurent-polynomials/226570#226570) thanks to [2, Exercise 3.17] (see also [4, Proposition 4.8]).

**Note 2.** The remarks and the proof below are not original.
They only consist in a specialisation of [3, Theorem 3.2], which can already be done with the results of [1] in the specific case of $L_N$.

To make the above isomorphism concrete, we introduce the following notation.

For $f = c_{-d}X^{-d} + \cdots + c_d X^d \in R \,(d \ge 0)$, we define
$$a_0^f := (a_0^{c_{-d}})^{t^{-d}} \cdots (a_0^{c_d})^{t^d}$$ and let $\phi_f \in \operatorname{Aut}(L_N)$ be defined by $$\phi_f(a_0) = a_0,\, \phi_f(t) = a_0^ft.$$

For $u \in U$, let $\psi_u \in \operatorname{Aut}(L_N)$ be defined by
$$
\psi_u(a_0) = a_0^u,\, \psi_u(t) = t.
$$

Finally, let $\tau \in \operatorname{Aut}(L_N)$ be defined by $$\tau(a_0) = a_0,\, \tau(t) = t^{-1}.$$

It is not difficult to check that all the above maps actually induce automorphisms of $L_N$; details can be added on demand.

The subgroup $\Phi:= \langle \phi_f \, \vert \, f \in R\rangle$ is an Abelian normal subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(L_N)$ which is isomorphic to the additive group of $R$. The subgroup $\Psi: = \langle \psi_u \, \vert \, u \in U\rangle$ is an Abelian subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(L_N)$ which is isomorphic to $U$ and $\langle \Psi, \tau\rangle \simeq U \rtimes C$.
Indeed, we have
$$(1)\quad \phi_f \circ \phi_g = \phi_{f + g}, \,\, 
\psi_u \circ \psi_v = \psi_{uv}$$
and
$$(2)\quad\phi_f^{\psi_u} = \phi_{u^{-1}f},\,\, \phi_f^{\tau} = \phi_{-\frac{\theta(f)}{X}}, \,\, \psi_u^{\tau} = \psi_{\theta(u)}$$ for every $f,g \in R$ and every $u,v \in U$.

We are now in position to prove the claim.

> *Proof of the Claim*. Observe first that $L_N$ identifies with $R \rtimes \langle t \rangle$ (to see this, use the map $a_0^ft^k \mapsto (f, t^k)$) where $t$ acts on $R$ via multiplication by $X$, i.e., $f^t := X \cdot f$ for $f \in R$.
> It is easy to verify that $\phi_f$ is a well-defined automorphism of $L_N$ which leaves $R$ point-wise invariant.
> Besides, as already noted by
> HenrikRüping in a comment, the normal subgroup $R$ is actually a characteristic subgroup of $L_N$. Indeed the subgroup $R$ in the previous decomposition identifies with the preimage of the torsion subgroup of $(L_N)_{ab} \simeq \mathbb{Z}_N \times \mathbb{Z}$, the abelianization of $L_N$.
> Let $\varphi \in \operatorname{Aut}(L_N)$. Let us prove that $\varphi = \phi_f \circ \psi_u \circ \tau^{e}$ for some $f \in R, u \in U$ and $e \in \{0,1\}$. As $\varphi$ preserves $R$, it induces an automorphism of $L_N/R \simeq \langle t \rangle$. Hence there is $f \in R, \epsilon \in \{-1, 1\}$ such that $\varphi(t) = a_0^ft^{\epsilon}$.  Replacing $\varphi$ with $\varphi \circ \tau$ if needed, we can assume, without loss of generality, that $\varphi(t) = a_0^ft$. Replacing $\varphi$ with $\phi_{-f} \circ \varphi$, if needed, we can assume, w.l.o.g., that $f = 0$, that is, $\varphi(t) = t$. Since $\varphi$ preserves $R$, there is $u \in R$ such that $\varphi(a_0) = a_0^u$. Expressing the fact that $\varphi$ is surjective, i.e., that $t$ and $a_0^{u}$ generates $L_N$, is easily seen to be equivalent to the fact that $u$ generates $R$ as an $R$-module. Therefore $u \in U$ and $\varphi = \psi_u$. We have thus demonstrated that $\operatorname{Aut}(L_N) = \Phi \cdot \langle\Psi, \tau\rangle$. The semi-direct product decompositions now follow from the relations (2).

---

- [1] F. Szechtman. "The group of outer automorphisms of the semidirect product of the additive group of a ring by a group of units", 2004.
- [2] C. Weibel, "The K-book", 2013.
- [3] M. Stein, J. Taback, "Automorphisms of Higher Rank Lamplighter Groups", 2015.
- [4] A. Genevois, R. Tessera, "A note on morphisms to wreath products", 2022.